# Libsvm in Java: exits after 0 iterations, no result

Tags: java, libsvm

Here is the code I have:

```
svmProblem.x = new svm_node [numSamples][numDims];
svmProblem.y = trainingY;
for(int i=0; i < numSamples; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numDims; j++) {
         svmProblem.x[i][j] = new svm_node();
         svmProblem.x[i][j].index = j;
         svmProblem.x[i][j].value = trainingX[i][j];
    }
    svmProblem.y[i] = trainingY[i];
 }

svmProblem.l = numSamples;
svm_parameter svmParam = new svm_parameter();
svmParam.probability = 1;
svmParam.kernel_type = svm_parameter.LINEAR;
svm_model model = svm.svm_train(svmProblem, svmParam);
```

and here is the message at the end of the execution:

```
optimization finished, #iter = 0
nu = NaN
obj = 0.0, rho = 0.0
nSV = 0, nBSV = 0
Total nSV = 0
```

I tried stepping it through the debugger, but without any success and I am pretty much stuck now. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: This piece of code doesn't print out any of the messages you specified. What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: The print message comes from the libsvm library itself. The problem is that there should not be 0 iterations, because that means that no training was done, which is absurd.

Comment: Hi were you able to find a solution to this ? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I realize this was asked years ago, but if this happens with anyone else, I'm going to guess that the value of `nu` chosen yielded an infeasible problem.

Note in the documentation,

```
nu <= 2 * min(#y_i = + 1, #y_i = - 1) / l <= 1
```

Ensure that the `nu` chosen honours these bounds. By default, `nu` is `0.5`.